# How to add/remove a value from stored html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

According to the user navigation to pages, i would like to show appropriate side bars. so I am basically getting `html` of side bar and putting in empty.

and i am storing the `sidebar` to object. before i add to object i would like to add an id to side bar. i am trying but not working;

here is my try:

```
var ob = {};

var catcheBars = {};
var sidebar = $('div.sidebar');
var catchedBar = sidebar;
sidebar.empty();

for(i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if(!ob.hasOwnProperty(i+'page')) {
        ob[i+'page'] = catchedBar;
        console.log($(ob[i+'page']).find('button').addClass('sidebar'+i)); //not able to add class
    }
}

$("#sideBar").html(ob['1page']); //nothing append to live..

console.log(ob);
```

my try is not working. when i do the mistake, or what is the correct way?
thanks in advance

**Update**

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0an0ypwu/)

Comment: I am sorry, actually i required this: `console.log($(this.cachePages[i+'sidebar']).find('h2'));` i would like to add the unique info to storing htmls

Comment: `hasOwnProperty([i]['sidebar'])` won't work. That doesn't resolve to a string

Comment: i am checking the property existance..is this  not work?

Comment: To be honest I don't really follow the logic of the `for` loop without you providing more context and initial definition of `this.cachePages`. You could end up storing the same thing in multiple properties of `cachePages`

Comment: I getting a side bar, and keeping in an object. when user require to move some information regarding the page, he can move a reference to the side bar. so each page will have their own side bars. when they toggle between the pages, they will see the save stuff in the side bars.

Comment: @3gwebtrain If possible , can post `html` , included `js` ? , create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net ? Thanks

Comment: ok. let me try for you. @guest271314, added my complete code in update. have a look, feel free to ask question.

Comment: Tried `if (!this.cachePages.hasOwnProperty(i+ "sidebar"))` ?

Comment: yes, still getting undefined. `for(var i = 1; i <= this.pageLength; i++) {
    if (!this.cachePages.hasOwnProperty(i+ "sidebar")) {
     this.cachePages[i+'sidebar'] = sideBarInnerContent;
     console.log($(this.cachePages[i+'sidebar']).find('h2'));
    }
   }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `empty()` function. it works fine.
here is he updated result

```
var ob = {};

var catcheBars = {};
var sidebar = $('div.sidebar');
var catchedBar = sidebar;

for(i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if(!ob.hasOwnProperty(i+'page')) {
        ob[i+'page'] = catchedBar;
        console.log($(ob[i+'page']).find('button').addClass('sidebar'+i)); //not able to add class
    }
}

$("#sideBar").html(ob['1page']); //nothing append to live..

console.log(ob);
```